# Rendering tweets on the web page

Tags: html, xslt, twitter, value-of

I have a web page which has a part to render filtered entries from twitter. This part of the page is created using XSLT (I am using Umbraco CMS). The problem is that when there is special characters such as ' in the twitter entry, although I used "disable-output-escaping ="yes"" but in IE it is rendered as & apos ;. In other browsers it is fine. What should I do to handle this issue

Regards,

Comment: `&apos;` character entity should be render in any browser as `'`. Unless there is no character entity, but something as `&amp;apos;` that would be render as `&apos;` as it should. Please, add input sample and desired output in order to clarify this question.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when there is
>   special characters such as ' in the
>   twitter entry, although I used
>   "disable-output-escaping ="yes"" but
>   in IE it is rendered as & apos ;. In
>   other browsers it is fine. What should
>   I do to handle this issue

Without showing your specific code you will receive only general answers to such question.

**Here is an example of two ways to produce an apostrophe without needing at all DOE**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <p>It's Monday today</p>
  <p>It&apos;s early morning</p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), produces this output**:

```
<p>It's Monday today</p>
<p>It's early morning</p>
```

**and it is displayed by IE like this**:

```
 It's Monday today

 It's early morning
```

Comment: <xsl:value-of select ="atom:content"  disable-output-escaping ="yes"/> This is the way that put atom entry on the page. When it  contains apostrophe is shows on IE &apos; but other browsers are fine!

Comment: @Nami. Never use DOE. DOE isn't required in your case.

Comment: Then the html code of feed will be shown! I want it to be rendered.

Comment: http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23testvoorklant open this page in IE you can find out the point :)

Comment: @Nami: This page displays perfectly well in IE. What's the point?